# Looking for workaround on streaming NotOptimized M4A files iOS

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, core-audio

I'm trying use **AudioFileStream service** and **Audio Unit** to streaming & play **NotOptimized M4A** files(the header is not at the beginning of the file) and I tried "StreamingKit", "FreeStreamer" and so on. none of them support it.

> err = AudioFileStreamParseBytes(self.audioFileStreamID, length, data, 0);

above returns (kAudioFileStreamError_NotOptimized)

I understand it. but is there a way to handle it? I googled a lot, only I got is "Overcast" did it.
https://twitter.com/OvercastFM/status/657992790161412096

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Finally I find solution and did it. just parse 'moov' atom before 'mdat'.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. And how did you do it?

Comment: @Harman just pushed my code here (last commit) https://github.com/newbdez33/StreamingKit it's just a demo anyway.